# dotnet restore warning NU1701

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core

I am using .NET Core with C#, and when I did `dotnet restore`, it gave the following error:

> PS C:\workspace\Arbitrator> dotnet restore
>
> C:\workspace\Arbitrator\Arbitrator.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'PusherClient 0.5.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
> C:\workspace\Arbitrator\Arbitrator.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'WebSocket4Net 0.14.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.

This package in problem is [PusherClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PusherClient/). I just followed the NuGet documents to import it. How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to wait until *PusherClient* is upgraded for .NET Core.

Referencing .NET Framework 4.6.1 (and below) from .NET Core is a [new feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/#user-content-reference-net-framework-libraries-from-net-standard) available since .NET Core/Standard 2.0 preview 2 / VS 2017 preview 15.3, and according to MS, *it can be thought of as a feature that helps you migrate .NET Framework code to .NET Standard or .NET Core over time*.

1. You can just suppress this warning

   - for a specific package

   ```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Contoso.Base.API" Version="1.0.3">
        <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
    </PackageReference>
   ```

   - for all packages

   ```xml
    <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
   ```

   [See scenarios 2 and 3 in NuGet wiki for ways to do it from GUI](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Errors-and-Warnings#user-scenarios).

   It is possible, though, that your application may fail in run-time
   when you call an API (like something from WPF) that is not supported
   by .NET Core. Another reason of a failure could be native APIs
   possibly used by *PusherClient*. So you should test it extensively.
   But in most cases, it will just work on all platforms where .NET Core
   is supported (for example, I have tested an application with
   *MathNet.Numerics* dependency and it worked on Linux even though
   *MathNet.Numerics* is also .NET Framework 4.6.1).
2. If you don't need your app to be cross-platform, just change its target framework to .NET 4.6.1 by adding the following to your csproj file:

   ```xml
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to suppress such warning?

Comment: Yes, put <PropertyGroup><NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn></PropertyGroup> in your csproj

Comment: Can't see a way to suppress the warning per `PackageReference` in the `.csproj` file. I did find an open issue on this very subject: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5740 . Cast your vote :)

Comment: "Referencing .NET Framework 4.6.1 (and below) from .NET Core is a new feature available since .NET Core/Standard 2.0 preview 2". AND THEN taken away soon after by Microsoft when they released .NET Core 3.0+ (5.x, 6.x, etc)

Answer (score 50):

As a side note, don't do this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Doing that will break any other NoWarn settings being picked up elsewhere, such as from a directory.build.prop file. Instead, do this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1701</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That way, any global settings are preserved.

Comment: That should be fine for being inside a `<PackageReference>` though, shouldn't it?

Comment: That really depends. My solution, which is fairly large, makes extensive use of the Directory.Build.Props file to set common settings across all the projects. One of those settings is a list of warnings to supress. 

In this case w/o the $(NoWarn) this project overrides that list and just has the single NU1707 supression.

Answer (score 8):

For .NET Core 1.x:

You need to tell the guys from PusherClient to make their project .NET-Core ready.

Comment: What makes the library not .NET-Core ready? It's already in nuget.org, so I thinks it's OK to use it?

Comment: @fluter PusherClient is a .Net Framework library. To use it on .Net Core 1.x, it would need to be changed to a .Net Standard 1.x library.

Comment: @fluter But [according to MS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/) it is a new feature of the 2.0 version of .NET Core that you can reference .NET Framework 4.6.1 (and below) libraries.

Answer (score 6):

As Yair pointed out, there is an open issue around this subject on GitHub: [github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5740](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5740).

Where the dependency being resolved with a fallback framework version is transitive, suppressing the warning for the referenced package will not work.

For example, Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient is dependent on Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core which isn't compatible with .NET Core 3.0, resulting in the warning. Adding NoWarn to Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient won't work.

As a workaround (You can see my post here: [Workaround On GitHub Issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5740#issuecomment-562515264)), you can directly reference the transitive dependency and use NoWarn against that package.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.3" NoWarn="NU1701" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" Version="16.153.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```