# Package was restored using .NetFramework instead of project target framework

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, devextreme

I created a new project with the DevExtreme ASP.Net Core Application template.
Then I changed the framework from .Net Core 1 to .Net Core 2.0
However when I try to build I get the following error.

```
Warning NU1701  Package 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.0' was restored using 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework 
'.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.  . This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

[image]

This problem is similar to [This question about Nu1701](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861229/dotnet-restore-warning-nu1701) However the package in question is DevExtreme.AspNet.Core  The name of the package indicates that it is meant to work with Core.

Comment: I tried updating DevExtreme.AspNet.Data to the latest stable version 1.3.0 but it did not help.

Comment: I think you should got help from this url -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861229/dotnet-restore-warning-nu1701

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dotnet restore warning NU1701](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861229/dotnet-restore-warning-nu1701)

Comment: seems I need to update nuget.config to reference DevExtreme 17.2

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the DevExtreme 17.2.2 Beta and use the DevExtreme 17.2 ASP.Net Core Application (.NET Core) template