# warning NU1701 using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core package in a new Net Core 3.1 project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Using VS 20129, I create a new Console Net Core 3.1 project.
I add the "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" nuget
At the moment, a warning appear:

```
   warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7
```

Why does this warning appear?  According the nuget page, this package does not have dependencies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861229/dotnet-restore-warning-nu1701 I think it answers your questions

Comment: Please be aware that `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` is the **old** nuget package for .NET Framework only. If you are using .NET Core you really need to use the new ASP.NET Core Identity package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio